# Command prompt(Windows 10) freezes/stops task on minimize/clicking anywhere outside of it

Tags: windows, command-prompt

Say I use `npm install xyz` and it begins the installation, and I minimize the window to do something else while it installs, the command prompt just doesn't proceed. I go back to check the progress, and it is still there. As soon as I click the command prompt again, it starts moving forward. This happens with all the package installer/downloaders I use, such as youtube-dl, pip etc. How do I make sure everything installs/downloads in the background?

Comment: Is it possible that you accidentally activate selection mode? It pauses the program as well. Check if the title bar says "Select".

Comment: no, this is not the case.